# How to remove padding created by ResponsiveGridLayout control in OpenUI5 (SAPUI5)?

Tags: css, padding, sapui5

I am creating a form using [OpenUI5](http://openui5.org/) and I noticed that when I am using the `ResponsiveGridLayout` layout, the form gets some padding (blue area around the input fields). Please see result here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G4NrKPMGdN4DACXZgZOg?p=preview

If I am using the `GridLayout` layout, the padding is as expected:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yp6Ul7gLDf0t88vMWrWD?p=preview

Any idea how I can get a form with **very a small padding** (like in `GridLayout` example), but in the same time I want to be able to use the **12-column grid system** so I can set the size on my input fields?

Ideally, the views need to be XML and to use OpenUI5 classes/controls if possible.

Comment: Both links lead to the same ResponsiveGridLayout project

Answer (score 2):

You could just swap the responsible style classes using .addStyleClass() and .removeStyleClass().

Not sure if it works, but thats the easiest possible fix I can think of that might be worth a try.